# Why are "TypeToken Collections" Considered Typesafe? (Effective Java #29)

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-safety, parametric-polymorphism

[Item #29](http://books.google.at/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=java+database+row+typetoken&source=bl&ots=yYLiLku6U2&sig=f04oXNFcCg-27FmAQLHWtjZMf-I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sxsNU4yVBqKnywOXgYJQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=java%20database%20row%20typetoken&f=false) in Effective Java presents a way to implement "typesafe" heterogeneous collections, which basically boils down to something like this:

```
public Class HeterogeneousContainer {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> container = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> put(Class<T> type, T instance) {
        container.put(type, instance);
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> type) {
        //essentially just 
        //      return (T) container.get(type);
        return type.cast(container.get(type));
    }
}
```

Which (I presume) is then to be used like this (by a producer):

```
List<HeterogeneousContainer> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
...
resultSet.add(new HeterogeneousContainer());
...
resultSet.get(rowIndex).add(Column1.class, column1Value);
resultSet.get(rowIndex).add(Column2.class, column2Value);
...
```

and like this (by the consumer):

```
for(HeterogeneousContainer row:resultSet) {
    Column1 column1Value = row.get(Column1.class);
    Column2 column2Value = row.get(Column2.class);
    ...
    //do something with the columnValues
}
```

My question now is why is this considered type safe? How is this any better than just putting column names into the map or just using a regular `List`/`List<Object>` and looking the columns up by index?

Does this effectively/practically in any way improve on the .getString/.getInt/.getXXXX approach of JDBC ResultsSets?

Comment: It's typesafe because you're guaranteed by the compiler to get an instance of T (or null) when asking for an element of type Class<T>. When you store  objects in a map by a String key, you have to cast the result after getting the object, and have 0 guarantee about its concrete type. So using the incorrect cast will cause a ClassCastException. Whereas in the above solution, no cast is necessary: the compiler enforces the correct type.

Comment: @JBNizet Right, thanks! It seems my understanding of "typesafe" was wrong in this context. This example is in fact technically typesafe, though typos (i.e. mixing up columns) can arguably still go unnoticed until eventually things crash during runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This class is considered typesafe, because even while it's doing class casting during runtime, this unsafe behavior is encapsulated, and you can't observe it.

- The `container` field is private, thus when thinking about type safety, you only have to check the code inside this class.
- The `put` method inserts a pair of the type tag `T` **and** an element of the type `T`. This is the only place where the `container` is updated, and it is guaranteed (at compile time) that the inserted element has the correct type tag.
- The `get` method **does** class casting in an unsafe way (`return type.cast(container.get(type))`), but as long as it is assured that the `container` is modified only via `put`, it can not fail. And above we saw that `put` is of course the only way to do that, this class **is** typesafe for its users.

To tell the truth, if you really want, you can break the type safety of this class for example by using reflection. Usually this does not matter, as you want to defend your class for being *accidentally misused* rather than *intentionally corrupted*. However, as you read *Effective Java* further, you will see that defending against such attacks is much more complicated.

Comment: I just ready the Effective Java Chapter on Generics and my understanding is different from your answer. Are you sure about your answer regarding `encapsulating unsafe behavior`? I don't think the behavior is unsafe; there is no manual casting; the type safety is guaranteed by the parameterized key. There is no guessing; everything is guaranteed by the compiler. The one caveat to this mentioned in the book is to use the key (`Class`) in its raw form. I would be also interested for you to add an example to your question about how you would use reflection to intentionally corrupt.

Comment: @lindonfox Indeed there is a manual cast in get(): `return type.cast(container.get(type))`. If you access the `container` via reflection, you can set a value of any type, and `HeterogeneousContainer.get` will fail (throwing a `ClassCastException`).

Comment: thanks for the extra details to help me understand. Upvotes!